# Merge two concecutive rows into one having the same keyset in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe having 1K rows, I want to combine the rows having same Keyset Name and ID into one 
e.g.
Actual Dataframe

```
ID Name Val1 Val2
1  XYZ  10    0
1  XYZ  0     20
2  ABC  10    0
2  ABC  0     15
```

Converted Dataframe

```
ID Name Val1 Val2
1  XYZ  10    20
2  ABC  10    15
```

Comment: Please don't change your question. If your question has changed, [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) after the prerequisite research.

Answer (score 1):

By using `groupby` + `max`

```
df.groupby(['ID','Name'],as_index=False).max()
   ID Name  Val1  Val2
0   1  XYZ    10    20
1   2  ABC    10    15
```